# Широко разводят руками или руки? Или всяко можно?

Tags: фразеология

> В такие моменты жители страны широко разводят руками, поднимают лицо к небу и нежно улыбаются: Итаааалия, говорят они.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Разводить рук**ами*** означает *удивляться, недоумевать. Разводить же руки* значит ***физически***  разводить их в стороны, удалять друг от друга. В вашем примере вроде имеется в виду первое, *значит, всё правильно.*